# Code coverage in a Haskell project that only builds an executable

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal

I have a cabal project that builds an executable.

When I run `cabal test --enable-coverage` I get the following error:

```
All 9 tests passed (0.98s)
Test suite giter-test: PASS
Test suite logged to:
/home/refaelsh/repos/giter/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.2.7/giter-0.1.0/test/giter-0.1.0-giter-test.log
Error: .cabal-wrapped: Test coverage is only supported for packages with a
library component.

Error: cabal: Tests failed for giter-0.1.0.
```

1. Can somebody please explain what is going on?
2. Is that error a normal thing to happen when my cabal project has only an executable and no libraries?
3. Should I just make a library of those part I wanna Unit Test and make my exe dependent on that library?

   1. If yes, is that the common practice in idiomatic Haskell?
   2. If yes, it feels like a code smell to make changes to source code and/or project structure to accommodate Unit Tests.

Comment: I think you can't depend on an executable isn't it? I am talking from the top of my head, but I'd say that if you want to import a function in your test suite, that function should be in a library not an executable component.

Comment: "it feels like a code smell to make changes to source code and/or project structure to accommodate Unit Tests" I feel the code smell is more having code that's not directly related to the executable in an executable cabal project and not a library.

Comment: @cafce25 I dont understand what are you saying. "code that's not directly related to the executable" - Why do you say that?

Comment: Because you want to unit test code from an executable, if it's complex enough to be unit tested I feel it belongs in a library even if at the moment you only use it in a single executable.

Comment: @cafce25 But why should it belong in a library? Just because it's complex? I disagree with you.

Comment: Well the developers of at least Haskell and Rust probably more languages disagree with you, of course ultimately that's all more opinions than absolute truths.

Comment: @lsmor "if you want to import a function in your test suite, that function should be in a library not an executable component" - Please explain why do you say that?

Comment: @RefaelSheinker because that's how cabal works (and I think other build tools. Again I am talking from memory so double check me). I general you have a library which exposes your functions (Public API), and the executable which has the entrypoint and maybe other not-part of the API related stuff. The executable obviously depends on the library. I think, components can't depends on executable, so when you write in your cabal file `build-depends: ...` you can not put you exe as a dependency, hence you can not import any function from it.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker it's also a more general part of Haskell's philosophy: implement as much as possible of your functionality in pure functions that don't know or care about _execution_ in the real world. Then in the end call those functions from a thin executable wrapper. Ideally, the executable is the only part that has any `IO` in it, but no functionality that is complicated enough to require unit testing. — Of course, in practice it's usually not quite so nicely separated, but you can still put most of the IO in a library and only call that from the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the underlying technical problem is covered in [this issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5415).  Cabal assumes that you don't want a coverage report on the unit test code itself, just the code being tested, so it invokes `hpc` in such a way that unit test code is excluded and only the source code actually being tested is included in coverage reporting.  This is easy to do if the code is part of a separately compiled library:  the library is covered, and any modules that are part of the unit testing are not covered.

However, if you have no `library` stanza, and only `executable` and `test-suite` stanzas that use a shared set of modules, there's no obvious way to distinguish the `test-suite` modules that are part of the unit testing and should not be covered from the modules that are part of the code being tested that should be covered.

More generally, Cabal has poor support for testing an `executable` stanza.  As per the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5415), the only way of actually testing an `executable` is to use a hack -- either specify `executable` and `test-suite` stanzas that share the same `hs-source-dirs` which ends up double-compiling everything, or else move everything important into a `library` and leave your `executable` as a stub.  You are probably using the former approach, rather than the latter, but both kind of suck.   The developers seem to have decided that the "move everything into a `library`" is the recommended approach, even if not all of the documentation and/or tutorial material makes this clear.

Note that the situation for Stack is similar -- the default templates typically have a stub application containing only a `main` function with everything else moved into a library.

I guess I would recommend moving your entire application (not just the parts you want to test) into a `library`, and writing a stub main function for your `executable` like:

```
module Main where

import qualified Lib

main :: IO ()
main = Lib.main
```

with both the `test-suite` and `executable` depending on the `library`.